# Retrieve post data using ssi

Tags: javascript, c++, post, ssi, shtml

I'm posting some parameters to a shtml file.
and I want to retrieve them from c++.
I'm done this simply as line below:

```
< !--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/my_file?${QUERY_STRING}"-->
```

**${QUERY_STRING}** sends all url parameters to my code.
Now the problem is this, How can I retrieve and pass them to c++.

simply I can say I want to do this: (POST Data --> shtml --> pass them to cgi).

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I'd suggest that you have a look into `cgic`. (since I know of it, though there's bound to be a c++ equivalent) Link: www.boutell.com/cgic/‎

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for your reply. I can retrieve post data using c++ but exactly my problem is that I couldn't pass POSTed data to c++.
I want to post data to the shtml and run a cgi query and pass POST data to that query. It's not important if that cgi is not c++ problem is on passing post data.
(POST data --> shtml --> pass to cgi)

Comment: You're welcome. Ahh. Sorry, I kinda missed that nuance of your problem. I've no idea how(if?) the serving of shtml files differs from html files. Id probably be tempted to use some PHP code that grabbed the POST data and then passed it onto the CGI. Failing that, perhaps you could use javascript and GET variables. These could be extracted from the URL with JS, before being passed onto the CGI. Bookmarked. I'm curious myself now, too.